# How to prevent image files being duplicated while importing nodes with the Feeds module?

Tags: feeds, media

I have a large catalog import where the items often refer to a single common image (such as "brand_logo"). When I import the images via CSV parser, if the item refers to the same image file, an incremented duplicate is created.

Example: Using the example files supplied with the module, I modified 2 books to use the same image file, which are imported to `files/field/image/` as `51JQbhO0MmL.jpg` and `51JQbhO0MmL_0.jpg`.

This causes the images directory to balloon to 20 times the size it should be (lots of shared images).

Honestly, what I would prefer to do is to upload the images to the site separately (manually, via FTP etc.) and just import the links to the images, but I haven't figured that one out either.

*(The data (files) is not being replicated, just the **images** are replicated.)*

Comment: Do you have a unique target setup in the mapping? If you don't, it will duplicate.

Comment: Yes, both product import and the reference import have Unique Targets.... In this example I am using the supplied example files (csv, prod import and ref import). They are not overridden.

Comment: Try deleting the import... if this is possible.  you will see an option, delete items, on the import page  (/import/whatever_your_importer is called)

Comment: After re reading your issue... I see that you will continue to have this problem no matter what. It is looking at the image as its own image for that node.  I am not aware of a way to check duplicates of a file field on an importer.

I would recommend doing an import of the catalog and using the file name as a flat URL field instead of importing the file... then in your node you should use the field to reference the image library using a template suggestion  (http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

It is a bit hackish, but if you mind the duplicates that much.. its your best bet.

Comment: I see two relevant issues that may help. http://drupal.org/node/1357934 discusses using a *reference* to the image instead of importing the image itself. http://drupal.org/node/1171114 was a feature request.  You might want to post a support request in the feeds queue in addition to following those issues.

Comment: I tried the patch available at http://drupal.org/node/1171114 which adds FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE to the FeedsParser.inc but it made no difference.

Comment: missed my 5 minute window-  I would prefer to import links since, in the csv, the images are refered to as local links ie: folder/ image.jpg. I'm sure there is an easier way. I'm just not good enough (yet) to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. What you need to do is to install the [Media Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/media_feeds) module.

In your CSV file there is a column called e.g. `image` and reference the image using `public://myimage.png`.

Then in your mapping delete the original image mapping and create a new image mapping. When you do this you will have a new option for the image mapping.  Make sure you set the target configuration to "**Source is exactly the filename**".

No more duplicated images.

Comment: Shane - I'm trying to follow what you did here.  One question do all the images have to the in the public folder first? Currently I am downloading the images from the url in the csv file in the feeds import process, and am getting duplicates that I don't want.

Comment: Hi, in my particular case I had all the images the public folder, I didn't try this on a remote url in csv.  Let me know if you came right.

Comment: Shane - No it didn't work for me with the url in the csv. Still duplicates :(

Comment: Tried. Does not work :( When importing it says things like "Failed to get the file object for public://0091.jpg."

Comment: Hi, not sure why you don't get the same result but just to be sure, the "public://0091.jpg" must be inserted with no quotes and the image must already exist in your Public file system path which can be found at admin/config/media/file-system , in my case it was sites/default/files

Answer (score 0):

There is some movement to resolve this issue (still in dev right now):

Apparently the official way going forward (will not apply to 7.x-2.0-alpha8 without errors):
"Allow user to choose the method of file handling" https://drupal.org/node/1171114

Alternatively, this patch will apply to 7.x-2.0-alpha8 but will not be committed:
"Allow the reuse of existing file entities instead of creating new ones" https://drupal.org/node/2093829

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against this issue for a while, my best option was to stop importing images into the nodes as files, but rather using [imagecache_external module](http://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) to reference the external image url and generating image styles from there. The module adds an Imagecache External Image formatter that behaves just like a normal image formatter in views and node displays.